# Torque heatmap on CartoDB with time control

Tags: carto, heat-map, torque

I am interested in create a Torque Heatmap in which you can see the events occured every year in one step, for twelve years in total. Every event has a aggregation or ponderation value (they are the number of times that something occurs in a place, 771 places surveyed). I tried two ways:
- Unique 771 places with ponderation value per year. I used 11 steps on cartodb_id so i have all 771 places shown every year (step) but ponderation value is missing (I used Torque Aggregation Function as "count (value)", "sum (value)" and "value" itself, not working).
- Adding a date field like "12/31/year" and replicating each place as many times as its ponderation value for this year, i used again 11 steps on "date field" and Torque Aggregation Function as "count (cartodb_id)". Now i can see intensity in aggregated points, but no correspondence in dates because there are not the same number of events in every year.

Can anybody help me?